# Standard Deviation of a sum of identical random variables

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation

In a variation of the famous "how many chips are in a bag of Chips Ahoy" inference investigation, I am asked to make a confidence interval for the number of chips in 50 cookies (the amount in a bag) by using a random sample of cookies from 3 or 4 bags. The random sample size is 20, about 6 or 7cookies from each bag. The problem tells me to calculate the standard deviation from that sample and then multiply it by 50 to get the st dev. for a bag. It refers to the linear transformation theorem. But based on the sum of random variables, I think that the standard deviation for the bag should be the sqrt50 * s and not 50s, since the variances add, and the stan dev is the sqrt of variance. Which method is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think this confusion can be solved by this way:

Suppose $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are $i.i.d$ with normal distribution   $N(\theta,\sigma^2)$

Let $Y=X_1+X_2+X_3$ then $Y$ has a $N(3\theta,3\sigma^2)$ distribution, you can see $Var(Y)=3\sigma^2$ and standard deviation is $\sqrt{3}\sigma$

But the question now is that you have three "identical" random variables

Now your $Y=3X$, and your $Y$ has a $N(3\theta,9\sigma^2)$， the standard deviation is $3\sigma$

Did you see the difference? For the first case it is three i.i.d different random variables, for the second case, it is one random variable repeated exactly three time ($X+X+X$ not independent any more,you also need to add up co-variance $Cov(X,X)$).

So this is why you need to multiply $50$ directly, but not $\sqrt{50}$

The key is that you have sum of $identical$ random variables (stated in your question), not sum of different $i.i.d$ variables.